# Modify Word Content Controls on the server side

Tags: .net-core, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, word-contentcontrol

I have a MS Word document with some content controls. I would like to set their content on the server side using .net core. How do I accomplish that? (I looked into the [NPOI](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI) library, but it seems the API only gives read-only access to content controls.)

Answer (score 1):

The [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/officedev/open-xml-sdk) can help with such tasks, see [Read and Create/Write Excel file in C# .NET Core](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/read-excel-file-in-dotnet-core-2-1/) for more information. Also you may consider using any thord-party components designed for the server-side execution.